# How to write large data file (csv) to Azure Storage with encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, azure-storage, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I need to implement below in C# (background web job):

- Call a stored procedure and get results (rows can be in millions - i.e. 100m so will be implementing pagination to return 500K at a time)
- Generate a `.CSV` file
- Zip it with encryption and store it in Azure Storage

As I need to deal with millions of records, I will need to implement batching - for instance, call the stored procedure, get 500K records, write the `.CSV` directly to Azure storage, and then fetch next batch, append the data in same file.

Here are my thoughts:

- Create blob
- Fetch batch, write to blob, repeat until all batches are written.
  Potential issue: I think I cannot append data to existing `.CSV` stored in Azure Storage. I cannot load existing file as it will be too big, I have to append the new data to an existing file without loading it in memory. Any suggestions here please.
- Encrypt it, and zip it

Is this possible, any suggestions?

Comment: You can append a blob in azure storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs. But I think that the problem that u have to solve is not the right one. My question is what will u ever do with such blob if it so big that u can never read it/ open it properly with any application after all.

Comment: The ideal solution would be streaming and asynchronous in something like a pipeline. Read row(s) from the database, convert to CSV, compress and write to the blob. Do it all async, and loop. However I don't think there's any way to do streaming async zip creation.